# Displaying multiple selected columns to string when using linq C#

Tags: c#, linq

I am selecting 2 columns from a database using linq. How do i add thoses values to a string. This is how far I got

```
          IEnumerator enumer = query.GetEnumerator();
          enumer.MoveNext(); 
          String state = enumer.Current.ToString();
```

It returns { state = 1, Count = 4 } I would like to only retrieve the sate value

Comment: Did you try `enumer.Current.state`?

Comment: I dont see state or count when I go enumer.Current

Comment: What is the type of `query`?

Comment: var DataTable to  AsEnumerable

Comment: var query = tblcsv.AsEnumerable()    (tblcsv is a datatable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to retrieve the first state value from the results. This is a working equivalent:

```
string state = query.Select(x => x.state.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();
```

The above is based on x being an anonymous type `new { int state, int Count }`

Comment: I get this error when I try that anonymous type does not contain definition for field

Comment: @CharlPotgieter You said it was a DataTable. If it is an anonymous type, please show how you're creating it. Edit your question and show more info.

Comment: @CharlPotgieter please mark this as accepted answer. If you don't know how, it is shown in images on the following : http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235